# Amazon default VPC, auto scaling and best practice

Tags: amazon-web-services, production-environment, autoscaling, amazon-vpc, vpc

Im building a dev and production environment in amazon and wanted to separate them by having separate VPC, however I noticed that when i have created new VPC's these cannot be used in auto scaling groups and only the default VPC can be used. Should I create separate AWS accounts for each environment or use different regions

Comment: You should be able to setup ASGs for any VPC? Are you not seeing all of your VPCs in the dropdown list?

Comment: @justcompile is right, you should be able to use autoscaling groups in any VPC.

Comment: Have you actually defined subnets for your new VPC yet? It sounds like there is something wrong with your new VPC, like you haven't finished setting it up yet, if it isn't available to use with autoscaling.

Comment: VPC and subnets seem to be correct, when i select ASG and my VPC i get this message 




None of the instances in this Auto Scaling group will be assigned a public IP address because you have not chosen to launch in your default VPC and subnet.

You can ensure a public IP address is assigned to instances launched with this configuration by selecting only default subnets of your default VPC.

Comment: That's a totally different issue than the one you described in your original question.

Comment: Are the subnets you are trying to use in your new VPC private or public subnets?

Comment: The instances are gettin public Ip so I believe they are public subnets

Answer (score 1):

I got same problem when I was setting up auto scaling. I solved it the following way:

When you create Launch Configuration you can select "Assign a public IP address to every instance" option as shown here:

[image]

That option should allow you to use custom VPC

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Launch Templates, then you have to edit the subnet properties.

Select the subnet, goto Actions->Modify Auto-assign IP settings, and enable "Auto-assign IPv4"